# Can you say anything interesting about a language knowing only that it is prefix-closed?

Tags: complexity-theory, formal-languages, computability

Suppose $L$ is an arbitrary formal language over a finite alphabet $A$, and suppose that $L$ is closed under prefixes (i.e. if $w \in L$, and $u$ is any prefix of $w$, then $u \in L$).

Knowing only this, can you give any positive or negative decidability or complexity results about $L$?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

If $P$ and $Q$ are languages closed under prefix, then
$P\cup Q$, $P\cap Q$, $P \cdot Q$, $P/Q$ are also closed under prefix. Also you can think of such a language $L$ as a directed tree. Define the graph/tree $G = (V,E)$ where $V = L$ and
$$E = \{(\mathit{prefix}(w),w) \mid w\in L \}$$
(the words are the nodes and the parent of every word is its prefix).
Note that I assume that $\mathit{prefix}(x) = \varepsilon$ for all $x\in\Sigma$, meaning that the prefix of a single symbol is the empty word. Thus the root of the tree constructed above is the empty word. The constructed tree can be easily transformed to a DFA recognizing the language (I think you can see how).

Answer (score 0):

Let $L$ be an arbitrary language. Since the set of all words is countable, we can think of $L$ as a subset of $\mathbb{N}$. Let $\ell_i = 1$ if $i \in L$, and $\ell_i = 0$ if $i \notin L$. Define the language $L'$ of all words of the form $\ell_1 \ldots \ell_n$. The language $L'$ inherits many properties of $L$, and is prefix-closed.

Comment: Properties like what?  And do you need some special property of the injection from $L$ to $\mathbb{N}$ or will any injection $L \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ work?

Comment: I will use the injection $\epsilon,0,1,00,01,10,11,000,\ldots$ (take binary representation of $n+1$ and remove leading $1$). The language $L'$ is computable iff $L$ is, for example. You can try your favorite properties to see whether they are also preserved.

Comment: You are assuming L is a binary language, but that answers my question well enough anyway (i.e. you need a particular injection).  This isn't so interesting then because all you are doing is a simple change of alphabet so of course a computable image of a computable language is computable and a computable image of a non-computable language is not (tautologically).  That is not even specific to prefix-closed languages but holds for any language and so doesn't answer my question at all.

Comment: My point is that there is absolutely nothing special about prefix-closed languages.

Comment: If $L$ is not over the binary alphabet, then this makes absolutely no difference. Use your imagination to generalize everything to arbitrary finite alphabets.